# Python - error when zipping files, 'L' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295

Tags: python, zip, filenames

I run this code for zipping folders and files.

```
def save_folder_as_zip(self, folder_to_zip, save_as):
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(str(save_as), mode="w", allowZip64=True)
    self.create_zip(zipf, folder_to_zip)
    zipf.close()

    return zipf

def create_zip(self, zipf, directory, folder=""):

    directory = directory.encode("utf-8")

    for item in os.listdir(directory):
        if temp_folder == directory + os.sep:
            continue

        try:
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, item)):
                zipf.write(os.path.join(directory, item), folder + os.sep + item)
            elif os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, item)):
                self.create_zip(zipf, os.path.join(directory, item).decode("utf-8"), folder + os.sep + item)
        except Exception, e:
            self.schedule.machine.log_warning(str(e))
```

But then I get this error:

```
'L' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295
```

Example on filename where this happens:

```
/[Wii]TrackMania[PAL][WiiSOS.com]/ws_tramap.iso
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
   save_folder_as_zip("/Users/f/Downloads/", "hei.zip")
File "test.py", line 13, in save_folder_as_zip
   create_zip(zipf, folder_to_zip)
File "test.py", line 26, in create_zip
   create_zip(zipf, os.path.join(directory, item).decode("utf-8"), folder + os.sep + item)  
File "test.py", line 24, in create_zip
   zipf.write(os.path.join(directory, item), folder + os.sep + item)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 1100, in write
   zinfo.file_size))
struct.error: 'L' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295
```

Comment: Which line triggers the error?

Comment: Is your file bigger than 4GB? And please paste the full traceback.

Comment: The directory beeing zipped is at total 6GB, but the file in the example is around 1GB.

Comment: Fine. Please, update your original post with the full traceback. And there is no other file in the directory at more than 4GB?

Comment: I have added the traceback to the original post now.

Comment: Some of the files may be larger than 4GB, but it does not fail on those files..

Comment: So it's not possible? Or is it something I can do?

Comment: I think this is related to [this bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue6434). If it is, you probably won't be able to solve your issue without touching to zipfile.py...

Comment: They say its solved using allowZip64=True, but I already do that.. Hmms, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be fixed applying the patch attached to this bug report:

http://bugs.python.org/issue9720

The problem arises when the file you are trying to include in the zip file is larger than 2^32-1 bytes in original or compressed form. In this scenario the library need to store -1 as the file size/compressed size and has to allocate some extra fields to store the actual size, which does not fit in a 32-bit dword.

For some reason the patch has not been accepted in 3.2 or 2.7.2+, but I have tested it and it works OK. I think it does not fix some corner case with writestr() method, but if you only use write() to store files it works great.